# Extra line breaks in minified code?

Tags: jquery, sublimetext2

I'm using the production version of jQuery and I see what appears to be extra line breaks

https://jquery.com/download/

Is this in the code itself or is sublime just wrapping the text even though I have word wrap turned off?

I'm just curious as to why jQuery or subilme would do this.

I'm not worried about it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed line breaks in the minified source code. Shouldn't be much of a problem though, as they only take 2 bytes more. The reason for it is that some browsers don't cope well with very long lines. In jQuery's [minifying tool script](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/build/uglify.js), they've specifically set the max line length to 32768 characters.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do they leave the line breaks in?

Comment: You should include your comment into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To check for yourself whether it's multiple lines, enable line numbers on the left margin. I have this line in my `Preferences` -> `Settings - Default`:

```
"line_numbers": true,
```

(See [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html) for more info on how settings work)

If the 3 lines each have different line numbers, they're 3 different lines.

If instead, only the first line have a number and the other two doesn't, they're wrapped lines.

[image: Example]